# Windows/Mac Githook For python

Tags: windows, git, unix, github

so I want to make a GitHook which removes `.pyc` files. So a simple shell script one line command would be `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete` and that's it. The problem is that some of my team members use Unix based Operating Systems where `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete` works fine, however some use Windows too where it doesent really work, so what can I do?

Comment: The hook can be written in Python.

Comment: Well, even by using Windows, they need to have GitBash installed, and gitbash has find command (and lots of other unix tools). Git can be integrated into `cmd.exe`, but I strongly recommend to not do it.

Comment: Late question: Why is this a problem exactly ... removing .pyc files? If you don't want to commit/push such files, just add them to .gitignore. You also didn't specify WHEN this hook needs to run.